# Changes to Pixel Shader aren't being Saved

Tags: directx, shader, directx-11, pixel-shader

I'm working on a DirectX program (I'm not using any wrappers). I'm trying to make a Pixel Shader. I made some changes to the Pixel Shader, it is not reflecting in the code when it is running.
This is the code I wrote for the Pixel Shader. (It is just returning the colour to white).

```
float4 main(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    //float4 baseTexture = txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);

    return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1);
}
```

Before I changed my code to this, my pixel shader was returning the colour from the vertex.

When I'm running my graphics debugger I see this pixel shader running. (The old code)
[The graphics debugger running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJzLe.png)

I'm making my HLSL into a .csh.

Also, I'm making my PIxel Shader like this

```
hr = m_Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Mesh, sizeof(PS_Mesh), nullptr, &m_PixelShader[PIXEL_SHADER_TYPE::ENUM::PS_MESH].p);
```

Why are the changes not reflecting? I have tried to give all the information. Please ask any other questions you need to. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time.

[Build settings for the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LJ4B.png).

Comment: It depends on how you have your build set up, but in this case you'd typically need to make a chain of dependencies so that updating our source HLSL file results in building the ``.csh`` which results in rebuilding the ``.cpp`` file that consume it.

Comment: I have edited the post to add the setup of the build. I'm sorry I still didn't understand how to solve this issue. Maybe the settings will make it clear.

Comment: Okay, I fixed this issue. I was making my shaders in the C drive and not to a relative path and that is why it always had the old shader. I fixed the issue of where I was outputting the .csh and then included the correct file too.